# python failed to serialize object by calling pickle.dump

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, paddle-paddle

I know that `pickle.dump()` does not work for `paddle.Tensor` objects. However, I did the following but `pickle.dump` still failed:

1. Define a Python class, `A`, containing an instance member, `x`, with type `paddle.Tensor`
2. Define a bound method for class `A` named `func`
3. Define a Python class, `B`, its construct method accepts an `typing.Callable` argument, and will set this callable object as its member `self.func`
4. `pickle.dump` an instance of class `B`, which I expected would succeed but actually failed

```py
import paddle
import typing


class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = paddle.to_tensor([1, 2, 3])

    def func(self):
        # this bound method will be passed to class B construct method as an argument.
        pass


class B(object):
    def __init__(self, f: typing.Callable):
        self.func = f


# main 
def main():
    a = A()
    b = B(f=a.func)

    # try pickle.dump(b) but failed.
    with open("./dumpfile", "wb") as f:
        # TypeError: can't pickle tensor object.
        pickle.dump(b, f)
```

Can anyone let me know how to dump object `b` successfully?

Given 2 classes `A` and `B`, and 2 instance `a = A()` and `b = B(.

I expect I can pass the `a.func` bound method to the `b.__init__` construct method as an argument, in the meantime, even if the `a` object has an member `a.x` which is type of `paddle.Tensor`, but still I can `pickle.dump(b)` successfully.

Comment: Can you try to convert the tensor into a numpy array using .numpy() function and then try to serialize it?